# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Email Invite in Local Environment Gets "The request URI resolves to an IP address which is in a restricted IP range"

Tags: openid, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement the https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite sample in a local environment for now. Everything seems to be working up until I click the link in the email. I have `https://jwt.ms` set as my redirect Uri, and when I click the link in the email I get to the jwt.ms site with an error

> "AADB2C: The request URI
>   'https://localhost:44315/.well-known/openid-configuration' resolves to
>   an IP address which is in a restricted IP range Correlation ID: [some guid] Timestamp: 2019-07-15 18:25:14Z"

This endpoint comes from the SignUpInvitation Policy provided in the sample, I changed the template value to my local host endpoint since I'm using a self signed cert to sign the token used in the email invite.

I can't find any hits for the above error message.. I'm not even sure where it's coming from. Is this custom policy not able to be implemented using a web service hosted locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD B2C is attempting to download the OpenID configuration from **localhost:44315** for the ID token.

This is not allowed.

You must either create a public endpoint for the **AADB2C.Invite** application over a secure tunnel to your local host (e.g. see [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)) or deploy the **AADB2C.Invite** application to a remote host, such as an Azure App Service.

Comment: thank you. i've deployed a branch in Azure and got it working now.

Comment: The same error I'm getting right now. I do need to debug it locally to make life easier. On Azure it works but it's slow to debug.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning ngrok. I have `<Item Key="METADATA">https://f7e7a7b7.ngrok.io/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>` in the `B2C_1A_signup_invitation` uploaded to Azure custom policies blade. The invite link is like this: `https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenantId/B2C_1A_signup_invitation/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=clientId&nonce=nounce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ff7e7a7b7.ngrok.io&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&id_token_hint=tokenHere`. When the invite link is clicked I'm still getting `a restricted IP range` error. Somehow it's replacing ngrok URL with localhost down the path. :|